# Button maintains padding even when set to 0

Tags: android

I dragged out a Button from the Widgets panel. I noticed it had some default padding. There is a lot of space around the text of the button, as shown in this [image: screenshot].

Look at that padding of the Button compared to the Facebook button. I tried setting the padding to 0 on all 4 corners, as shown in the code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" android:padding="0dp" android:paddingBottom="0dp" android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp" android:paddingRight="0dp" android:paddingStart="0dp" android:paddingTop="0dp"/>
```

Yet the button looks the same. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need to change is the `android:minHeight` attribute. Give it a try.

Comment: It did have a minimum height. It generated it without my knowledge.

Comment: Try to lower the minHeight value, something like `android:minHeight="0dp"`